# The best place to change tableview frame at loading

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'am using custom shadow image, and i need to shift table view by 11 points.

Here is how i'm doing it:

```
self.frontTableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frontTableView.frame.origin.x, 
self.frontTableView.frame.origin.y+11,
self.frontTableView.frame.size.width, 
self.frontTableView.frame.size.height);
```

Im using it in numberOfSections method, which is probably not the best place - because when the view disappear and appear again my tableView is as it was.

So where is the best place to change tableview frame?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it either within the nib itself or in `viewDidLoad` - not in any of the delegate methods, which you won't know when or how many times will be called.

Comment: for some strange reason it doesn't get done in ViewDidLoad - probably the table view haven't loaded?

Comment: @Devfly that's unusual, how do you instantiate your table view?

Answer (score -1):

use this method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.frontTableView = [UITableView new];
   self.frontTableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frontTableView.frame.origin.x, 
   self.frontTableView.frame.origin.y+11,
   self.frontTableView.frame.size.width, 
   self.frontTableView.frame.size.height);
      //other custom methods . . . 
}
```

if you make some change in tableview during executing, dont forget to call the method
[self reload frontTableView];

Comment: What's going to happen when the view is first appearing and the table and view property are not loaded?